# Adding an attachment to email: permission denied

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail

http://pastie.org/4185959

I've used this code to make a mailing app that takes in authenticating parameters within the code. Sending the plain mail alone works fine, but adding the attachment is an issue, commenting out the line m.addAttachment() makes the mail send successfully even though I pass the path of a file correctly. Here's the code I use:

```
class MailSender extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer>
    {

        ProgressDialog pd = null;
        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPreExecute()
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd = new ProgressDialog(MailSenderActivity.this);
            pd.setTitle("Uploading...");
            pd.setMessage("Uploading logs. Please wait...");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();

        }

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
         */
        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {


            Mail m = new Mail("from_mail@gmail.com", "password");

            String toAddresses = "to_mail@gmail.com";
            m.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
            m.setFromAddress("from_mail@gmail.com");
            m.setMailSubject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device.");
            m.setMailBody("Email body.");

            /*try {
                ZipUtility.zipDirectory(new File("/mnt/sdcard/logs/"), new File("/mnt/sdcard/logs.zip"));
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                Log.e("MailApp", "Could not zip folder", e1);
            }*/

            try {
                m.addAttachment("/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/test.jpg");

                if (m.send()) {
                    System.out.println("Message sent");
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 2;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e);
            }
            return 3;
        }

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pd.dismiss();

            if(result==1)
                Toast.makeText(MailSenderActivity.this,
                        "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            else if(result==2)
                Toast.makeText(MailSenderActivity.this,
                        "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else if(result==3)
                Toast.makeText(MailSenderActivity.this,
                        "There was a problem sending the email.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

And the Mail.java class

```
public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {

    private Multipart attachements;


    private String fromAddress = "";
    private String accountEmail = "";
    private String accountPassword = "";
    private String smtpHost = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private String smtpPort = "465"; // 465,587
    private String toAddresses = "";
    private String mailSubject = "";
    private String mailBody = "";


    public Mail() {
        attachements = new MimeMultipart();

    }

    public Mail(String user, String pass) {
        this();
        accountEmail = user;
        accountPassword = pass;
    }

    public boolean send() throws Exception {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        //props.put("mail.smtp.user", d_email);
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpPort);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", smtpPort);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        try {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);
            session.setDebug(true);

            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            // create the message part
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            //fill message
            messageBodyPart.setText(mailBody);
            // add to multipart
            attachements.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            //msg.setText(mailBody);
            msg.setSubject(mailSubject);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress));
            msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(toAddresses));
            msg.setContent(attachements);

            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
            transport.connect(smtpHost, 465, accountEmail, accountPassword);
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
        attachements.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }

    private String getFormattedDate(Date date)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
        return sdf.format(date);
    }

    @Override
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(accountEmail, accountPassword);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the fromAddress.
     *
     * @return <tt> the fromAddress.</tt>
     */
    public String getFromAddress() {
        return fromAddress;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the fromAddress.
     *
     * @param fromAddress <tt> the fromAddress to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setFromAddress(String fromAddress) {
        this.fromAddress = fromAddress;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the toAddresses.
     *
     * @return <tt> the toAddresses.</tt>
     */
    public String getToAddresses() {
        return toAddresses;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the toAddresses.
     *
     * @param toAddresses <tt> the toAddresses to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setToAddresses(String toAddresses) {
        this.toAddresses = toAddresses;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the mailSubject.
     *
     * @return <tt> the mailSubject.</tt>
     */
    public String getMailSubject() {
        return mailSubject;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the mailSubject.
     *
     * @param mailSubject <tt> the mailSubject to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setMailSubject(String mailSubject) {
        this.mailSubject = mailSubject;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the mailBody.
     *
     * @return <tt> the mailBody.</tt>
     */
    public String getMailBody() {
        return mailBody;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the mailBody.
     *
     * @param mailBody <tt> the mailBody to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setMailBody(String mailBody) {
        this.mailBody = mailBody;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the addAttachment method only takes in a string, specifically the file path. I've passed the file path directly, as I have a file named 'test.jpg' in my Pictures folder, but I'm still getting this message:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/test.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I've added permissions for both the INTERNET and EXTERNAL_DATA_STORAGE, so that's not the issue. It seems as though for some reason I cannot access this file within the Pictures folder.

Here's the location of the file within Amaze:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7gsa.png

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but note that you can simplify your code by fixing these [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  Also, make sure you're using the official [JavaMail for Android](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#JavaMail_for_Android).

Comment: Do you have this permission android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned above.